# Python3 list-slicing with negative arguments

Tags: list, slice, python-3.4

I have a difficulty on understanding why python3 slicing method with negative index numbers do the following:
my list is for example: `Numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
now if I tell python

```
>>>Numbers[::-1]
```

he says:  `[4,3,2,1]`
so it increments the list from the last index by -1 (or from behind to the first index)

Can anyone explain the philosophy and how this happens?

Comment: I guess the default arguments for the `from` and `to` parameters depend on whether the `step` parameter is positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

When redoing the exact same steps my output is different from yours, and behaves as expected, i.e. reversing the list:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:18:07) 
>>> Numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> Numbers[::-1] 
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The slicing syntax `[from:to:step]` is respected since `my_list[::-1]` will take all elements in the list from `start` to `end` with a step of `-1` which means starting from the end. Hence it will **copy** the list and reverse it:

```
>>> id(Numbers) == id(Numbers[::-1])
False
```

Any chance you are doing anything with your variable between the two calls ?